# Search forms and redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a search form. It has an `if` and I want it to trigger only if a record exists or not. But is not triggering correctly, because it runs even when the record does not exist. If the name does not exist, Rails throws an error saying that the method is nil, instead of executing the code inside the `else` part of the code. How can I fix this?

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row"></div>  
  <%= form_tag(doctors_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "please enter your name" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      <br>
      <div>
       <% if @doctors.exists?(name: params[:search])%>
          <%= @list_patients.each do |patient| %>
          <p>Appointment for patient <strong><%= patient.name %></strong></p>
          <hr>
          <br>
          <% end %>
       <% else %>
           <h5>your name is not on our database, please regsitry <%= params[:search] %>.</h5>
       <% end %>
     </div> 
  <% end %>
 </div>  
</div>
```

This is the controller

```
 def index
    @doctors = Doctor.all
    if params[:search]
      @doctors_exists = Doctor.where("name like ? ", params[:search]).all
      @list_patients = Doctor.find_by(name: params[:search]).patients.order('created_at DESC')
    else
      @posts = Doctor.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have any user for whom for some reason the name is ""(empty)? Also is params[:search] always present?

Comment: Can you post the controller code where you assign `@doctors`?

Comment: you'd have to show the error

Comment: @maxple, hi! this is te error: 
undefined method `patients' for nil:NilClass ,

@soupdog I just put the controller in the comments, thank you!, 

@sahil No, I create 5 record with the name included for each doctor.

Comment: this will fail for any search query that is not an exact match on a doctor's name: `Doctor.find_by(name: params[:search]).patients`

Comment: Even when is not the condition for the IF? Because I only used that to get the name of the patients and when the name of the doctor is correct it return a list of the name of patients related.

Comment: @maxple Alright, I understand now. But why is the query triggering even when the condition is not true?. I removed the query "Doctor.find_by(name: params[:search]).patients" and the code is working, Any idea how could I print the name of the patients from another table?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the same issue if you try this?

`<% if @doctors.where(name: params[:search]).exists? %>`